# Java How to find the first login of the month

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jfoenix

I am writing a program in which I have to figure out the first time a person has logged in to my JavaFX application in the current month. I have been trying to find out an answer but with no result.
Kindly help thank you!

## Edit 1:

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKC13.png)
In the image there is an outstanding balance which is stored in the MySQL server and I want to email that amount at the first login of each and every month.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You probably have to store login sessions; with names and timestamps; and then search those. A lot of stuff, so what exactly is your problem? Hint: show code and explain your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need to save that date for each user somewhere and determine it every time a user successfully logs in to the app.

A simple general approach might be something like this:

```
/* Called after successfull login */
public void loginWasSuccessfullForUser(User user)
{
    Date first_login_in_month;

    /* Get the saved date. */
    first_login_in_month = getFirstMonthlyLoginForUser(user);

    /* Is it in the current month? */
    if (first_login_in_month != null
        && dateIsInCurrentMonth(first_login_in_month))
    {
      /* Logging in again this month... nothing to do. */
      return;
    }

    /* No date saved yet (first login) or first login this month. */
    first_login_in_month = getCurrentTimeFromSomewhere();
    saveFirstMonthlyLoginForUser(first_login_in_month, user);
}
```

Comment: Umm this looks good. I thought of storing the info in the database but was faced with some conflict. I thought of adding a flag with each users' info and during first login, I'd change the flag's value but the problem was in resetting the flag.
What piece of information will getFirstMonthlyLoginForUser() return?